# Fill transparent doesn't work as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

```latex
\documentclass[crop]{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz
{
    \draw [fill=blue] (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
    \draw [stroke=black, circle, fill=transparent]  (1, 1) circle (1);
}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: a black circle within a blue square]

while I'd expect it to produce

[image: a white circle within a blue square]

What I'd like to actually do is have a shape which *erases* the stuff behind it. Currently I fill it with a background color, but I have to change that twice to accommodate a black and white background. The questions relating to that topic usually have answers which works for selected PDF viewers, but I'm using `dvisvgm` to convert into `svg` which isn't able to do that.

`fill=none` just makes the circle fill nothing, and blue remains.

Comment: You cannot "erase" something that has already been drawn. Use the even-odd rule fill instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to erase something that has already been drawn. Either you paint over it using the background color (white in this case) or you use the even odd rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \draw [fill=blue, even odd rule]
    (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2)
    (1, 1) circle (1);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Understood, thanks for the answer. Now I'm curious about what the _color_ `transparent` actually means then, if not erase? Why does it show up as black?

Comment: @DesmondWillowbrook Short answer: `transparent` is only meaningful for shadings. For a long answer please read Chapter 23 Transparency in the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=354).